# Происхождение слова "сова"

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

Давно хотел спросить, но вопрос, может быть, глупый. Слова "сова", "совать", "засовывать" — однокоренные или просто похожи? Не от них ли произошло название птицы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Сова.** Происходит от праслав. формы, от
> которой в числе прочего произошли:
> др.-русск., сербск.-церк.-слав. сова
> (др.-греч. γλαύξ), русск., укр. сова́,
> сербохорв. со̏ва, словенск. sóva,
> чешск., словацк. sоvа, польск. sоwа,
> в.-луж., н.-луж. sоwа, полаб. süwó.
> Родственно др.-бретонск. соuаnn — то
> же, бретонск. kаоuеn, кимрск. сuаn
> "ночная сова", др.-в.-нем. hûwо
> "сова", hûwilа – то же, hiuwilôn
> "ликовать", ср.-в.-нем. hiuweln,
> hiulen "стонать, выть", арм. sаg
> "гусь", лит. šaũkti, šaukiù "кричать";
> наряду с этим, с иным задненёбным:
> ка́ва "галка", лит. naktikóva "сова,
> ночной ворон", kóvas м., kóvа ж.
> "галка", др.-инд. kā́uti "кричит".
>
> **Совать.** Происходит от праслав. формы, от которой в числе прочего произошли: др.-русск. совати, сунути "метать (копье)", ст.-слав. совати (ῥιπίζειν πυρί; Супр.), русск. совать, су́нуть, укр. со́вати, со́ваю, болг. со́вам "засовываю", сербохорв. су́нути, су̑не̑м "плеснуть; насыпать; толкнуть кого-либо; напасть на кого-либо", словенск. sováti, sújem, súniti, sȗnem "толкать", чешск. souvat, sunout "двигать, совать", словацк. роsunúť, польск. suwać, sunąć, в.-луж. suwać, sunuć, н.-луж. suwaś, sunuś. Родственно лит. šáuti, šáuju, šóviau "совать, сажать (хлеб в печь)"; "стрелять", латышск. šaũt, šaũju, šaũnu, šãvu "стрелять; быстро совать, толкать", далее сравнивают с готск. skewjan "идти", а также с др.-в.-нем. sсiоʒаn, др.-исл. skjótа "стрелять, двигать, толкать", алб. heth "бросаю, вею зерно", аор. hodha.

Как видно из этимологии двух слов, родственной связи между ними нет, так что они просто созвучны.